# Duplicate items in the legend

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend, dojo

I have recently created a web map that uses the legend snippet from the ESRI JavaScript API website.
https://developers.arcgis.com/en/jav...et_legend.html

It works great for the most part, but has one issue, there are duplicate entries in the legend. The rest services that I am using are all symbolized properly without duplicates. The method I'm using to add the services to the map is through a feature layer.

[image]

This is the exact code in my .js file.

```
dojo.connect(myMap, 'onLayersAddResult', function (results) {
    var layerInfo = dojo.map(results, function (layer, index) {
        return { layer: layer.layer, title: layer.layer.name };
    });

    if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
        var legendDijit = new esri.dijit.Legend({
            map: myMap,
            layerInfos: layerInfo},
            "legendDiv");
            legendDijit.startup();
        }
    });

//Layers are added to map
myMap.addLayers([featureLayer1, DMSL_StudyArea]);
```

Any information would help.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. May be I think two layers which you have added at last using addlayer method has few common fields that's the reason your are getting duplicate legends. Try to add single layer then check. Legend code is perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Sunil. I was wondering about the addLayer method myself, but if things are being added twice, wouldn't all of the items in the legend be repeated instead of the particular ones? All of the items you see in the picture are from one service/mxd sitting on our ArcGISServer.

Comment: if possible please put your code at jsfiddle so that we can check.

Comment: The server won't work on your end because it is within our network for now. I have no way to publicly release the services either due to privacy issues. Either case, here's the link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/xC6RH/ Thanks!

Comment: As of now this is favorite for 2 people, did you ever find the answer? Perhaps fire a console message to help debug it?

Comment: Honestly, it sort of resolved itself. I wrote that whole code block again and ran it (like a year ago), and it just ran perfectly. Might have been the order I was doing things...but I'm not sure. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Hope you figured this out.

I would check the layer itself in ArcMap and make sure you don't have duplicates in there, such as two layer groups that are identical.

Comment: Thanks!That's what I did.. I recreated the service layer (republished) and rewrote the code block. It just started working.